# How to prevent my site page to be loaded via 3rd party site frame of iFrame

Tags: php, python, iframe, http-headers, frame

How can I find out that my page is embedded as a frame to other site during page loading? I guess referrer request header can't help me here? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, John, I can't say I need complete solution here, just moving direction is enough, after I'm finding answer on my question I'm always post it as an answer, this is only way I can participate in community.

Comment: Note: Setting the meta tag is useless! For instance, <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny"> has no effect. Do not use it! Only by setting through the HTTP header like the examples below, X-Frame-Options will work. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You cannot check it from the server's side, but you can use javascript to detect it after the page has loaded. Compare `top` and `self`, if they're not identical, you are in a frame.

Additionally, some modern browsers respect the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header, that can have two values:

- DENY – prevents the page from being rendered if it is contained in a frame
- SAMEORIGIN – same as above, unless the page belongs to the same domain as the top-level frameset holder.

Users include Google's Picasa, that cannot be embedded in a frame.

Browsers that support the header, with the minimum version:

- IE8 and IE9
- Opera 10.50
- Safari 4
- Chrome 4.1.249.1042
- Firefox 3.6.9 (older versions with [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/722))

Comment: Since I stumbled in here via a google search, I'll add that Firefox added X-FRAME-OPTIONS in August, 2010 with FF3.6.9:  
http://michael-coates.blogspot.com/2010/08/x-frame-option-support-in-firefox.html

Comment: From owasp https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Defending_with_X-Frame-Options_Response_Headers

Comment: This answer is outdated. See [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

Answer (score 46):

Stackoverflow includes some JS to test it (`master.js`). This is the relevant part of it:

```
if(top!=self){
    top.location.replace(document.location);
    alert("For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.")
}
```

But keep in mind that JS can be disabled.

Comment: This approach is particularly useful if you want to get a message to either the person that's putting your content in an iframe, or the end user of their site that's looking at your content in the iframe.

Answer (score 33):

For [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/contentsecuritypolicy), you can use CSP (Content Security Policy), which is a standard. The following header will prevent the document from loading in a frame anywhere:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
```

(IE 11 needs the `X-` prefix, though). You can also change `'none'` to the origin on which framing is allowed, such as your own site.

To cover the older browsers, this is best used together with [@Maerlyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2896705/1079573).

Comment: Your answer is not clear enough with all due respect. Is this header code or PHP? For example.

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook This is a HTTP header that should be part of the response to the browser when serving a page. It's not PHP code, though you could use PHP to send it; see [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 15):

you can prevent loading you page in an iframe with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( window.self !== window.top ) {
    window.top.location.href=window.location.href;
}
</script>
```

this code change address of container of your page's iframe to your page address and force container to show your page.

Comment: `sandbox` attribute on iframe allows to forbid such framing escaping hacks. So this way is not a secured way to prevent framing, in case your concern is security issues.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can block a specific domain if you don't mind your content in some locations but don't want it on a certain site.  For example, if `offendingdomain.com` was embedding your content, you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.referrer.indexOf("offendingdomain.com") != -1) {
        window.location = "http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=oHg5SJYRHA0";
    }
</script>
```

This would check the parent document's location and see if it's the `offendingdomain.com` that is embedding your content.  This script will then send that iframe to a certain famous youtube video as punishment.  In effect they just Rick-Rolled themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Use javascript to check if it was loaded on iframe by placing the following script at the end of your php file and redirect to a page that displays warning or notice that your page should not be loaded using iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(top.location != window.location) {
    window.location = '/error_iframe.php';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace hosname to domain name

```
if (window.top.location.host != "hostname") {
    document.body.innerHTML = "Access Denied";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I using this PHP code on top of the header

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != 'yourwebsite.com'){
   header('location: yourwebsite.com');
}
```

if someone did iframe your site it will redirect to your website