# How to prevent embedding my web page inside an iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent my site page to be loaded via 3rd party site frame of iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe)

How can I prevent others from embedding my web page inside an iframe?

Comment: hmm? could you please rephrase that?

Comment: if i call my web page inside a iframe it will run....
i want to stop this...
can u help me..

Comment: If you have access to .htaccess, you can set it to add the X-Frame-Options: Deny header. Solutions based on Javascript can be subverted by adding the sandbox attribute to the iframe tag, which blocks JS. The real problem is companies who provide a link, which goes to a proxy that fetches the page, strips it of anti-embedding measurements, and pass the result to the browser. The only solution I can think of is using a firewall to block those proxies to your website, which boils down to whack-a-mole.

Answer (score 13):

Another solution:

```
if (window.top !== window.self) window.top.location.replace(window.self.location.href);
```

Comment: +1 for conciseness and only using in-built functions

Answer (score 4):

With Javascript:

```
if(window.top==window){
    // not in iframe/frame
} else {
    if(parent.parent.someFunction){
       parent.parent.someFunction();
    } else {
       alert("parent.parent.someFunction() not defined.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Up-voted. Although I would re-direct to the actual web page in the else statement rather than throw a scary-looking alert message to the end user, whom may not understand what's going on.

Comment: @Martin: Of course this one is an example. He can do anything in the statement.