# http iframe is not loading on an http site in Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, iframe

This is not related to an https site or iframe in any way.

I am trying to load an http iframe inside of an http site within the same domain. However, the iframe will load and then the head and body of the iframe is stripped of content and appears white.

This issue is appearing in Firefox and Internet Explorer. The iframe shows fine in Chrome. Also, there is some active https content (script includes and such) that load inside of the iframe, but to my understanding that shouldn't matter if the main URL and iframe URL are both http.

-- EDIT --

It looks like it could be related to how I'm dynamically loading the iframe in:

`$("body").html("<iframe id='iframe-contents' src='" + url + "' style='width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; height: 100%; margin: 0;'></iframe>");`

Comment: Can you link to a resource that shows the issue, or perhaps share some code? Which version(s) of Firefox and Internet Explorer did you test? Are there any error messages in the browser's console output (press F12).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a situation where I can share the code, and I'm not sure a sample code would replicate it :(. The console in Firefox is showing a SHA-1 certificate error, recommending use of algorithms stronger than SHA-1.

It is the latest Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set up everything correctly, there could still be some javascript on the site you are trying to embed that is preventing you from doing so.

If you didn't write the code of the site you are trying to embed yourself, this seems rather likely, especially since your symptoms perfectly match what will happen when you try to include [facebook inside an iframe](http://ami.responsivedesign.is/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com#)

You can prevent your website from being embedded inside an iframe as statet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279357/how-to-prevent-embedding-my-web-page-inside-an-iframe)

hope this helps

edit: just saw that you mentioned it works fine in chrome, so it's probably another issue, sorry

Comment: 1) The site works in chrome, so it is allowed (whereas facebook will not work in any browser)
2) I am embedding my domain withing the same domain.

Comment: yeah, I overlooked that, sorry