# javascript iframe trouble

Tags: javascript, iphone

After adding `iframe` tag in html of dashcode (web application IDE for iphone).

I am getting an error which says:

> For Security reasons framing is not allowed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe

Answer (score 0):

that sounds strange to me, 'couse i'm using iFrame in my off-line embedded web app and it is working.
I use dashcode just to edit my html and not using a dashcode template, i think that dashcode locks it just when you use and start a project with his own templates...

If you need it i can send you a html page loading one other in a iFrame...

luca

Comment: yes please if you can send a sample application where iFrame is used to load an url..

Comment: ok, you can download a cleaned project with a UIWebView loading a main html which loads 2 different pages in iFrames when you clik on 2 buttons:  http://meronix.altervista.org/iFrameSample.zip   luca

Comment: Thanks Chap,But I am working on Dashcode, no Webview is there how to proceed now????

Comment: well, you can see/open/edit the html pages you can find inside the "html" folder. You can try to copy/paste the html/code to your pages to see if it works. As you can see my pages works good if you open them on a iphone with safary.