# How to prevent other websites putting my web page in their iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent my site page to be loaded via 3rd party site frame of iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe)
>   [How to Block Iframe call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881139/how-to-block-iframe-call)

I don't want other website use my website content by iframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) response header, this will tell the browser wether it should show the webpage in a frame or not. E.g.

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```