# CSRF and iframes

Tags: php, csrf

When preventing CSRF attacks I should take the following steps:

1. User logs in, set session cookie and generate CSRF token
2. User submits form (with token) and it should match the token in session

But when an attacker uses an iframe it’ll also send the session cookie which results in the same CSRF token, also forms within the iframe will contain the token. So the attacker gets access.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent my site page to be loaded via 3rd party site frame of iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe)

Answer (score 10):

You're missing the fact that IFrames do not get full access to Window objects under the Same Origin Policy unless their origins match. [Details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access):

> JavaScript APIs such as iframe.contentWindow, window.parent,
>   window.open and window.opener allow documents to directly reference
>   each other. When the two documents do not have the same origin, these
>   references provide very limited access to Window and Location objects

Therefore the attacker's frame will not be able to read `window.document` nor the CSRF fields within any contained form.

You do have [Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) to worry about, however. This is where your site is loaded in an IFrame but is then made transparent, and the user is enticed into clicking something on the attacker's page (e.g. "Win an iPad click here") which in fact causes the click to actually happen on a sensitive function within your page.

Uses of the [`X-Frame-Options: DENY`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Secure_Headers_Project#X-Frame-Options) and Content Security Policy [`frame-ancestors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#frame-ancestors) directives are recommended to prevent framing of your site.

Comment: But how would Clickjacking be useful if the form being attacked within the iFrame is empty and the attacker have no access to it to fill it using JavaScript?

Comment: There are two main scenarios here. 1) If the form only consists of buttons. 2) Any form present can be prefilled using query string or form values supplied by a POST. There might not be any CSRF checking at this stage as filling the form isn't considered a state changing action.