# Web address URL different from actual website

Tags: security, url, frame, webaddress

My client is facing a potential security issue. Someone is displaying their website at another web URL which is not my client's.

Upon investigation it is found that the miscreants are using `frame` tag to display client's entire website on their domain.

- I want to ask if any user information can be so extracted from client's website?
- If there is any coding that can prevent frames to be used to display the client's website by others?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link. This is one solution.

```
if(top!=self){
    top.location.replace(document.location);
    alert("For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.")
}
```

[How to prevent my site page to be loaded via 3rd party site frame of iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe)