# Beginner HTML: <iframe> not working as I'd like to

Tags: html, iframe

so I am still fairly new in coding and started with HTML, because I think it is the easiest and quickest way to get into it.

Im now using w3schools.com to develop my skills and now I am trying to use the iframe tag. When I just used as scr "https://www.google.com" it said, that google is refusing to connect. Then I downloaded the google website and added it to the folder and changed it to scr"google.html" it shows the Page of google, without fancy imaging of Google, which is already an advancment, however, I am unable to actually search something, then I get the error again "Refusing to connect".

Anyone an idea why this is happening and how to solve that?

FYI: My Website is not running on a Server, but I am connected to the Interenet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every website can prevent third-party domains from embedding their content. 
(How? [How to prevent my site page to be loaded via 3rd party site frame of iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe)).

So the problem is not with your code. Google has denied access to embed it inside iframes.

Comment: Oooh okay, that makes sense! Guess Google just doesn't like me :P Cheers!