# wordpress site into iframe login page not working getting cookies error

Tags: wordpress, cookies, iframe

I have a wordpress site up and running, now I wanted to put wordpress site into my another website into the iframe. But in the chrome I am getting following error.

> Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress

**But in safari it is working** there is no such cookies issue.

I am using latest version of the wordPress.

e.g my parent site is at : `abc.com`

and then my wordPress site is running at : `abc.com/wordpress`

In my parent site (abc.com) I have added iframe and source of the iframe is `abc.com/wordpress`.

How we can fix this issue.

Note: cookies are enabled in the chrome, chrome is okay for serving the landing and other unauthenticated pages.

Let me know if someone has already using WP in iframe and login page is okay.

Comment: Have you tried in incognito mode? try from your mobile. Also try clearing the cookies in the problematic browser.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, I tired in the normal mode. I tried to clean all the cookies and cache but still I had the same problem.

Comment: Maybe you have X-FRAME-OPTIONS set, check [How to prevent my site page to be loaded via 3rd party site frame of iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896623/how-to-prevent-my-site-page-to-be-loaded-via-3rd-party-site-frame-of-iframe)

Comment: @Buttered_Toast,  X-FRAME-OPTIONS is set to allow from my abc.com domain and it is okay. What could be other setting for the cookies, is it the case that now chrome is not allowing or drupal has something specific changes related to this?

Comment: @Tranquillity did you get the solution? Would be helpful if you post it.

Comment: @FaisalAlvi I think I did not get a solution for the chrome.